# How to replace localhost url with my domain or IP dynimcally for the reset password link Python Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

url(r'^usernewdata/$', views.UserNewFormView.as_view())

```
if userdata.is_active:
            subject = 'Request For Account Activation'
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            message = render_to_string('resetemail.html', {
                'user': userdata,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(userdata.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(userdata),
            })

            mail_func(request.user.user_role_id, request.user.org_id).send_messages([EmailMessage(
                subject,
                message,
                emailfrom(request.user.user_role_id, request.user.org_id),
                [userdata.email, ],
            )])


def get_current_site(request):
    """
    Check if contrib.sites is installed and return either the current
    ``Site`` object or a ``RequestSite`` object based on the request.
    """
    # Imports are inside the function because its point is to avoid importing
    # the Site models when django.contrib.sites isn't installed.
    if apps.is_installed('django.contrib.sites'):
        from .models import Site
        return Site.objects.get_current(request)
    else:
        from .requests import RequestSite
        return RequestSite(request)
```

get_current_site is function in python in shortcuts.py.

This is My Template file.

```
    {% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.email }},

Please click on the link below to reset your password:
This URL is valid for only 5 mins.

http://{{ domain }}{% url 'reset-password-link' token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

I get this when i create user in mail.

> Hi dxxxx.com,
>
> Please click on the link below to reset your password: This URL is
> valid for only 5 mins.
>
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset-password-link/619-478bd672cbbc6d1f6a0d/

How can i change http://127.0.0.1:8000 to current system Ip or domain, this should be dynimcally change where which domain or ip user has been created, from now it has been created from localhost it show localhost.

Answer (score 1):

add 'django.contrib.sites' and 'django.contrib.sitemaps' in your installed apps and also add SITE_ID = 1 in settings.py then migrate.

your settings.py looks like

```
#...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
#... already exists apps

'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',

# ... your other apps
]
# ... other code in settings section
SITE_ID = 1
```

Login to django admin panel, there is site section on it. Edit one if exists (might be example.com) or create a new one if not with your domain name. This only works in production, if your are in local development stick with 127.0.0.1:8000